# Ajax post , server feedback "Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, datatable

I have a table that is built using dataTables, and the data is coming from the ajax attribute, however, I'm getting an error on the ajax:

> `Ajax post , server feedback "Method Not Allowed"}`

[image: Method Not Allowed Error]

I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const accountType = localStorage.getItem("acc_type");

    console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken);


    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        url: "http://192.168.30.03:3000/api/log/list",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          limit: 13,
          offset: 1,
          search: "",
          id: 0,
          start_id: 0,
          end_id: 0,
          event: "",
          user: "",
          message: "",
          type: "",
          start_time: "",
          end_time: "",
          order_by: "desc",
          order_column: "id"
        }),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log("SUCCESS", response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          console.log("ERROR", response);
        },
        columns: [
          { data: "id", title: "id" },
          { data: "event", title: "event" },
          { data: "user", title: "user" },
          { data: "message", title: "message" },
          { data: "type", title: "type" },
          { data: "created_at", title: "created_at" },
        ],
      },
    });

    table.draw();

  });
  
</script>
```

---

Comment: that would suggest that the *server code* does not allow `POST` method -but you haven't posted your server code

Comment: my other coworker is working on server side, we front-end and back-end communicate via API, instead of server code , I can show that `from website use api  call server is not working (the core of this problem)` but `via fastAPI use api  call server is working`  [pic-use fastapi work ](https://imgur.com/a/R3ryAxZ)

Comment: `we front-end and back-end communicate via API, instead of server code` ... huh? so there is no server code on the server side? what "back-end" are you running? What API has your co-worker *written*? Does your API writing co-worker know what you're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

-here is the .js I came up which fix my problem

```
var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem") || [];

$(document).ready(() => {
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const API_URL = "http://192.168.30.03:3000/api/log/list";
    var rowData;

    console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken);

    var accountType = localStorage.getItem("acc_type");
    var buttons = [
        {
            extend: "csv",
            text: "CSV",
            className: "btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg",
        },
        {
            extend: "excel",
            text: "Excel",
            className: "btn btn-outline-success btn-lg",
        },


    ];


    var buttonRow = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    
    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
        var buttonCol = $('<div class="col"></div>').append(button);
        buttonRow.append(buttonCol);
    });
    
    
    if (accountType === "OP") {
        buttons = buttons.slice(2);
    }

    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        processing: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: API_URL,
            type: "POST",    
          
            contentType : 'application/json', // 不能用 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            data: function(d) {
                d.search = d.search.value
                console.log(d)
                return JSON.stringify(d)
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
            },
            dataSrc: function (response) {
                console.log("DATA", response);
                return response.data;
            }
        },

        columns: [
            { data: "id", title: "id" },
            { data: "message", title: "message" },
            { data: "type", title: "type" },
            { data: "user", title: "created_by" },
            { data: "created_at", title: "created_at" },
        ],
        dom: '<"row"<"col"B><"col text-right"l><"col"f>>rtip',
        buttons: buttons,

        error:  function(response){
            console.log("ERROR",response);
          }
    });

    table.draw();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).